# How do I prevent multiple columns on SWT Vertical ToolBar?

Tags: eclipse, swt, toolbar

I'm creating a vertical SWT ToolBar:

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar( parent, SWT.RIGHT | SWT.VERTICAL );
```

And then adding items to it:

```
for ( MyObject myObject: myObjects ) {
    ToolItem toolItem = new ToolItem( toolBar, SWT.NONE );
    toolItem.setText( myObject.getLabel() );
    toolItem.setImage( myObject.getImage() );
}
```

The toolbar is created correctly, but as some labels are too long, there are some cases in which new items are created on a second column, in front of the previous item.

So, instead of getting a toolbar that looks like

```
Item with a very long label
Tiny item
Little item
```

I get a toolbar that looks like

```
Item with a very long label
Tiny item                    Little item
```

If the long label is long enough, a third column will appear.

Does anyone know if there's a way to prevent the creation of a new column on the toolbar?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably platform-dependent issue. Is it on Windows ?